# marginnote adds spacing before paragraph

Tags: spacing, marginnote

## Unwanted spacing

The `marginnote` package introduces some extra spacing between the section header and the start of a paragraph (this is unwanted). How can this be corrected?

## Example

[image] [image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Shorten the spacing after section headings
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Normal spacing}
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{Unwanted spacing}
\marginnote{Something very long and interesting. Something very long and interesting.}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code with a simple `\marginpar` seems to improve the layout:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Shorten the spacing after section headings
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Normal spacing}
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{Unwanted spacing}
 \leavevmode\marginpar{\raggedright Something very long and interesting. Something very long and interesting.}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I add a `\leavevmode` it adds a small indent at the start of the paragraph. (My real document uses `\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}`, and hence why I've noticed it). Can this side effect be resolved as well?

Comment: It probably adds an interword space. See if adding `\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font` (just after `\leavevmode`) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `\hrule` makes the spacing more obvious.  Evidently `\marginnote` adds a `\strut` at the beginning instead of a simple `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Shorten the spacing after section headings
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Normal spacing}
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{Unwanted spacing}
%\hrule
\smash{\marginnote{Something very long and interesting. Something very long and interesting.}}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This adds in the space for an entire line and gets rid of the vertical alignment.

Comment: Did you run it twice?  \marginnote gets its vertical position from the previous run.